# Check if String is a concatenation of elements in a list

Tags: python, string

Is there an elegant way (preferably pythonic too) to check if a String *s* is a concatenation of elements of a subset of set *L*? An element of *L* may appear more than once in *s*.

For example:

```
L = set(["a", "ab", "c", "e"])
```

Then "abac" is a valid concatenation of elements of a subset of *L*

"aaaaaaa" is also a valid concatenation.

But "ad" is not since "d" not in L.

Comment: you probably want something like [`if s in itertools.permutations(L)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: Can you only use each such element once? if not, it can be a regexp

Comment: @RNar that will give exponential running time.

Comment: @greggo you can use more than once

Comment: I would approach it from the other side - removing the elements of the subset from the original string s. Are you able to use each of the set elements more than once ?

Comment: Why the downvote... This question definitely doesn't deserve that.

Comment: @xiamx you never stated there was a run time limit ;) also, it is quite broad so a downvote is kind of expected...( not me)

Comment: @RNar well, definitely elegant though, I should add :)

Comment: When you say "concatenation", are you considering whitespace at all? Should it be ignored? Is it guaranteed not to appear? In other words, are you doing something like `L = ['a', 't', 'c', 'g']; s = "attcgactaagc"` or something like `L = ["dog", "the", "lazy", "happy", "brown", "sleepy"]; s = "the lazy brown dog"`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell thx, added clarification

Comment: Excellent. Maybe an invalid concatenation or two as well, for completeness?

Comment: @JoshCaswell yep done.

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
L = ["no", "force", "in", "the", "verse", "can", "stop", "me"]
# make this: "(?:no|force|in|the|verse|can|stop|me)*$"
r = re.compile( "(?:" + "|".join(L) + ")*$")
r.match("shiny")  # -> None
r.match("canme")  # -> not None
```

That works for the given set of strings. There is a function in the `re` library to quote strings (escaping  `|` etc) so that you can safely make such an expression at run time.

```
r = re.compile( "(?:"  + "|".join( re.escape(s) for s in L) + ")*$" )
```

It will match no matter how many times the substrings appear; and strange results might occur, if some of the strings are prefixes of others and so forth.
It may have nasty runtime. If all of the strings are distinguished easily from each other by their beginnings, it shouldn't.

Comment: Potentially nasty runtime, though.

Comment: No, actually this one could run really fast, perhaps linear time. It's a finite state automaton.

Comment: @xiamx but what if you have "ab" and "alon" and "abalone" and "along" and  "gnu" and such, there may be a lot of back-tracking? But if no common prefixes, it should just identify each string as it comes up and move on to the next.

Answer (score 2):

you could try a recursive approach.

```
def isIn(s,L):
    if not s: #checks for empty string
        return True
    index = 1
    while index-1 < len(s):
        if s[0:index] in L and isIn(s[index:],L):
            return True
        index+=1
    return False
```

some notes on this:

- this depends on the fact that python boolean operator `and` is greedy (which Im pretty sure it is). Which means that if `s[0:index] in L` is false, then it wont even assess the next. to be safe, you can do a nested if (put the recursive call inside the if block)
- a `s in set` expression has an average run time of `O(1)` so ensure that L IS in fact a set, otherwise, `s in list` is average `O(n)`

This is of course not a very elegant solution as it pretty much is a hack of the regex solution given by greggo. Worst-case is, I believe, `len(s)^2` which isn't TOO bad, but it could definitely be better....

Answer (score 0):

This works under the assumption that the elements in `s` from `L` are separated by a delimiter, a space here:

Let's use this test data

```
s = "hello world foo foo"
L = set(["foo", "bar", "baz", "hello", "world"])
```

First, tokenize *s* and turn it into a set:

```
tokenset = set(s.split())
```

Then simply subtract `L` from `tokenset` and check if the result is empty:

```
if not tokenset - L:
    print("s is a concatenation of elements from L")
```

Comment: but what about `helloworldfoofoo`?

Comment: The problem statement doesn't seem to provide convenient delimiters to split on.

Comment: There may not _be_ delimiters: consider `chars = ['a', 'g', 't', 'c']; good_s = "attgacgttcg"; bad_s = "aggtcvgtaac"`.